# In a how general setting can smoothed fix-point iterations be used to numerically approximate matrix equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question, matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization, fixed-point-theorems

In numerical methods one method for numerically approximating solutions to non-linear scalar equations is to use a so called [fix-point-iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration). The other day I was wondering if this maybe could be used also for approximating solutions for matrix equations.

---

**Own work** : The matrix equation

$$X^3 - M_1 = 0$$

Where $M_1$ is a known affine transformation and $X$ is some unknown matrix.

Which affine transformation if applied three times is equivalent to $M_1$

We can apply a fix point iteration:

$$X_{new} = M_1 {X_{old}}^{-2}$$

And an $\alpha$ parameterized smoothing:

$$X_{n+1} = (1-\alpha) (M_1 {X_{n}}^{-2}) + \alpha X_{n}$$

Experiments show that this can be used with linear (exponential) convergence:

[image]

Found a solution for scaling $S=0.59$, rotation $\varphi = 0.088662$, translation $[-0.22994,1.1658,0.4583619]^T$:

$$M_1 = \left[\begin{array}{llll}0.58776&0.052249&0&-0.22994\\-0.052249&0.58776&0&1.165834\\0&0&0.59008&0.4583619\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

Can we derive / find out for which class of equations this can be used?

Will it's efficiency be limited to polynomials or even special cases of polynomials?

Comment: It appears from your example that the iteration should only work if you know that solution, $X$ is invertible.

Comment: @DOUGLASBRUNSON $X_1$ is initiated randomly to a matrix quite close to the unit matrix. It is true that we might not be able to assume that we can find ${X_n}^{-1}$ in a general setting. But for this example we are.

Comment: Newton iteration can be used to solve matrix equations : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282689907_Newton's_method_for_a_nonlinear_matrix_equation

Comment: @JeanMarie Yep, I am aware =) I am just trying to expand my knowledge a bit further. Thank you for the link.

Comment: See paragraph 3.2 of this [interesting document](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/694/1/high86p.pdf)